# How to create a nuxt.js app without create-nuxt-app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

Please I wish to know how I can create a nuxt app without the create-nuxt-app template. I am pretty new to it and I don't want to download the template but start a new project (say with Vue.js) and incrementaly add nuxt functionality to my app. I Googled but can't find a relevant post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add it incremetaly since it's a framework build upon Vue